# How to get a hierarchical data in Entity Framework or in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following tables,

*TblFaq (a record represents a diagram), PK: FAQId, FK: FAQWebPageId*

[image: TblFAQ]

*TblFaqNode (has all nodes for all the diagrams), PK: NodeId, FK: FAQId*

[image: TblFAQNode]

*TblFaqNodeMapping (has information about which node is connected to which node), PK: FAQNodeMapId, FK: SourceNodeId [parent], DestNodeId [child]*

[image: TblFAQNodeMapping]

I need to form a C# object as shown in the JSON below, by either using Entity Framework LINQ to SQL query (Database First Approach) or by writing a stored procedure to return JSON/XML.

I'm not looking for a result set which says which node connects to which one because again I've to loop all the records recursively to create the C# object which is not efficient and as of now I'm only able to do this, as shown in below query.

```
SELECT
    FAQ.FAQWebPageId,
    FAQ.FAQId,
    FAQ.Name,
    FAQNode.NodeId,
    FAQNode.[Data],
    FAQNode.FAQNodeTypeId,
    FAQNode.FAQNodeBranchTypeId,
    FAQNode.IsStartNode,
    FAQNode.IsEndNode,
    FAQNodeMap.FAQNodeMapId,
    FAQNodeMap.SourceNodeId,
    FAQNodeMap.DestNodeId,
    FAQNodeMap.Label
FROM TBL_LY_FAQ AS FAQ
JOIN TBL_LY_FAQNode AS FAQNode
ON FAQ.FAQId = FAQNode.FAQId
LEFT JOIN TBL_LY_FAQNodeMap AS FAQNodeMap
ON FAQNode.NodeId = FAQNodeMap.DestNodeId
WHERE FAQ.FAQWebPageId = 1
ORDER BY FAQNode.NodeId
```

[image: Simple query to get parent-child relationship]

Also, the nodes in *TblFaqNode* which are having *IsStartNode* as 1 should always be the top nodes in the result i.e. nodes not having any parent and the whole result set will be filtered by the where condition for *FAQWebPageId*.

Directly through the database query I want to get the C# object in the hierarchical format as shown in the below JSON, Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
[
   {
      "FAQWebPageId":1,
      "FAQId":1,
      "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
      "NodeId":1,
      "Data":"Do you have any openings for BA",
      "FAQNodeTypeId":1,
      "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":3,
      "IsStartNode":true,
      "IsEndNode":false,
      "FAQNodeMapId":0,
      "SourceNodeId":0,
      "DestNodeId":0,
      "Label":null,
      "Adjacents":[
         {
            "FAQWebPageId":1,
            "FAQId":1,
            "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
            "NodeId":2,
            "Data":"yes we have an opening, it requires 2 + years in product development",
            "FAQNodeTypeId":2,
            "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
            "IsStartNode":false,
            "IsEndNode":false,
            "FAQNodeMapId":1,
            "SourceNodeId":1,
            "DestNodeId":2,
            "Label":"Technical BA",
            "Adjacents":[
               {
                  "FAQWebPageId":1,
                  "FAQId":1,
                  "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
                  "NodeId":20,
                  "Data":"What are the services offered by your company",
                  "FAQNodeTypeId":1,
                  "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
                  "IsStartNode":false,
                  "IsEndNode":false,
                  "FAQNodeMapId":29,
                  "SourceNodeId":2,
                  "DestNodeId":20,
                  "Label":null,
                  "Adjacents":[
                     {
                        "FAQWebPageId":1,
                        "FAQId":1,
                        "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
                        "NodeId":8,
                        "Data":"We offer services in HR, LMS, IT and staffing",
                        "FAQNodeTypeId":2,
                        "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
                        "IsStartNode":false,
                        "IsEndNode":true,
                        "FAQNodeMapId":28,
                        "SourceNodeId":20,
                        "DestNodeId":8,
                        "Label":null,
                        "Adjacents":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "FAQWebPageId":1,
            "FAQId":1,
            "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
            "NodeId":3,
            "Data":"yes we do have, Financial BA requires 5 years experience",
            "FAQNodeTypeId":2,
            "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
            "IsStartNode":false,
            "IsEndNode":false,
            "FAQNodeMapId":2,
            "SourceNodeId":1,
            "DestNodeId":3,
            "Label":"Financial BA",
            "Adjacents":[
               {
                  "FAQWebPageId":1,
                  "FAQId":1,
                  "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
                  "NodeId":4,
                  "Data":"Does your experience match ?",
                  "FAQNodeTypeId":3,
                  "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":2,
                  "IsStartNode":false,
                  "IsEndNode":false,
                  "FAQNodeMapId":3,
                  "SourceNodeId":3,
                  "DestNodeId":4,
                  "Label":null,
                  "Adjacents":[
                     {
                        "FAQWebPageId":1,
                        "FAQId":1,
                        "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
                        "NodeId":5,
                        "Data":"Please apply at our careers page",
                        "FAQNodeTypeId":2,
                        "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
                        "IsStartNode":false,
                        "IsEndNode":true,
                        "FAQNodeMapId":4,
                        "SourceNodeId":4,
                        "DestNodeId":5,
                        "Label":"Yes",
                        "Adjacents":[

                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "FAQWebPageId":1,
                        "FAQId":1,
                        "FAQName":"CareersFAQ",
                        "NodeId":6,
                        "Data":"no problem, you can still share us your profile by registering at our careers page, we will contact you if any match in future",
                        "FAQNodeTypeId":2,
                        "FAQNodeBranchTypeId":1,
                        "IsStartNode":false,
                        "IsEndNode":true,
                        "FAQNodeMapId":5,
                        "SourceNodeId":4,
                        "DestNodeId":6,
                        "Label":null,
                        "Adjacents":[

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Use dapper (multi mapping) : https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md